# MVC 3 navigating through various views based on the click of button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am having a button that is placed in _layout.cshtml as i want to be seen on each and every view.
Based on the click of the next button i want to navigate through various views i have created.
Please reply as it is urgent and i am new to MVC 3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

Using a variable in session to track the current view you could have a button which when clicked went to the next view in a list of views when compared to the current view in the session where the view was a partial view.  However, this approach defeats the purpose of decoupling and MVC in general.